# Does SQL Server Table-Scan Time depend on the Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, query-performance

I observed that doing a full table scan takes a different time based on the query. I believed that under similar conditions (set of columns under select, column data types) a table scan should take a somewhat similar time. Seems like it's not the case. I just want to understand the reason behind that.

I have used *"CHECKPOINT"* and *"DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS"* before querying to make sure there is no impact from the query cache.

**Table:**

- 10 Columns
- 10M rows Each column has different densities ranging from 0.1 to 0.000001
- No indexes

**Queries:**

**Query A:** returned 100 rows, time took: ~ 900ms

```
SELECT [COL00]
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Test]
WHERE COL07 = 50000
```

**Query B:** returned 910595 rows, time took: ~ 15000ms

```
SELECT [COL00]
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Test]
WHERE COL01 = 5
```

** Where column COL07 was randomly populated with integers ranging from 0 to 100000 and column COL01 was randomly populated with integers ranging from 0 to 10

**Time Taken:**

- **Query A**: around 900 ms
- **Query B**: around 18000 ms

What's the point I'm missing here?

Comment: There are about x100 more rows to fetch in the second test, that only could explain why it took 20 times longer

Comment: Switch to a count(1) as the result.

Answer (score 3):

> Query A: (returned 100 rows, time took: ~ 900ms)
>
> Query B: (returned 910595 rows, time took: ~ 15000ms)

I believe that what you are missing is that there are about x100 more rows to fetch in the second query. That only could explain why it took 20 times longer.

Comment: Yap! seems like that. 
However what I thought is, isn't table scan mean going through actual row data? if that's the case anyway both queries have to go through all the data (I mean fetch data). Or is there a separate cost involved in fetching?

Comment: As an example think I used 
SELECT [COL07] FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Test] WHERE COL07 = 50000 and 
SELECT [COL01] FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Test] WHERE COL01 = 5
(which behave similar to what I had in question )

now I'm selecting whatever in the where clause. If the query has to go through all values for the columns in where clause to find the matching rows, why there is an additional fetching cost?

Comment: It still has to actually do something with the rows when you find them, which takes time as well. If you tried Select count(1) from ... instead of Select *, that would minimise the amount of processing to be done per row, and I suspect the times would be a lot closer.

Comment: Ya, I checked with count(1) and Query B now takes only a very small time. I might have to dig deep to understand what that *something* is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two columns have different density of the data.

Query A, COL07: 10000000/100000 = 100

Query B, COL05: 10000000/10 = 1000000

The fact that both the search parameters are in the middle of the data range doesn't necessarily impact the speed of the search. This is depending on the number of times the engine scans the column to return the values of the search predicate.

In order to see if this is indeed the case, I would try the following:

COL04: 10000000/1000 = 10000. Filtering on WHERE COL04 = 500

COL08: 10000000/10000 = 1000. Filtering on WHERE COL05 = 5000

Considering the times from the initial test, you would expect to see COL04 at ~7200ms and COL05 at ~3600ms.

An interesting article about [SQL Server COUNT() Function Performance Comparison](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4460/sql-server-count-function-performance-comparison/)

Answer (score -1):

> Full Table Scan (also known as Sequential Scan) is a scan made on a database where each row of the table under scan is read in a sequential (serial) order

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan)

In your case, full table scan scans sequentially (in ordered way) so that it does not need to scan whole table in order to advance next record because Col7 is ordered.

but in Query2 the case is not like that, Col01 is randomly distributed so full table scan is needed.

Query 1 is optimistic scan where as Query 2 is pessimistic can.

Comment: None of them are ordered